# Laravel 5 updating single row limit doesn't work

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, limit

I need to update single matching record in db (PostgreSQL), but Limit method doesn't work with Update method. This code will update all records matching Where condition instead of single record.

```
DB::table("records")
  ->where('need_moderate','=','no')
  ->where('locked_per_time','<',$date_now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
  ->limit(1)
  ->update(["locked_per_time"=>$locked_per->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"),'locked_by'=>$mdkey]);
```

How do I work around this so only single record would be updated?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike with [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/update.html) or [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) update statements, using `LIMIT` directly on [PostgreSQL update statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html) is not possible. So chaining the `limit(1)` method to the Query Builder instance does nothing, because the [`compileUpdate`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/PostgresGrammar.php#L121) method from Laravel's `PostgresGrammar` class that is responsible for compiling the query, only compiles the where statements.

You could however overcome this by having a condition that uses a subquery which only returns one row that will be updated. Something like this should work:

```
DB::table("records")->whereIn('id', function ($query) use ($date_now) {
    $query->from('records')
          ->select('id')
          ->where('need_moderate', '=', 'no')
          ->where('locked_per_time', '<', $date_now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
          ->limit(1);
})->update(["locked_per_time" => $locked_per->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 'locked_by' => $mdkey]);
```

The `whereIn('id', ...)` condition assumes your table has a column named `id` that can be used as a unique identifier so it can find the first row that matches your conditions in the subquery.

Comment: Unfortunately code didn't work properly. Even with 2-4 threads, same records are still released to different threads. I assume that inner Select of second thread is  executed before first thread Update.

I would appreciate help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Please provide a more detailed context on how you would like the update process to work.

Comment: With each query we update record by changing its locked_per_time. After this we take data from this record. While current date is less than locked_per_time this record shouldn't be avaliable to other threads and never taken twice. But even with code you've provided when I'm running several threads they somehow get same record at the same time before first thread does Update locked_per_time

Comment: I also thought about [Pessimistic lock](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#pessimistic-locking)  but i'm not sure it's going to help with multithreading with lots of requests at the same time. I also consider raw request to db cos it will be single transaction for sure, have you done something like that and whats the pros and cons of both options? Thanks